# Fullcalendar copyright headers with premium license

Tags: fullcalendar, copyright-display, fullcalendar-premium

I would like to use FullCalendar in my project.

I have two questions:

- With the Premium license, will the copyright headers be removed? or can I remove the copyright headers?
- When the license expires, one year after purchase, will the copyright headers be visible again automatically?

I expect it doesn't have to be shown with the premium license. Is that so?

Thanks

Comment: You can't claim the code as your own, of course.  But with the Premium license, the code must be obfuscated or minified, which usually removed the comments.  What do you mean by "shown"?  The user is not going to see it unless they fetch the code separately.

Comment: Contact the fullcalendar [sales team](https://fullcalendar.io/contact-sales) if you have any questions regarding premium licensing.